# Iterate over all refs values in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access all ref values in my component and do something with them (for example, create payload to send to a server)

I was trying to do a simple for..in loop and than use getDOMNode().value on every ref but it doesn`t work.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

getAllRefsValues: function() {
    for(ref in this.refs) {
        console.log(ref);
        // ref.getDOMNode().value doesnt work here 
    }
},
render: function() {
    return (
     <div>
        <button onClick={this.getAllRefsValues}>Get all props values</button>
        <input type="text" ref="test1"/>
        <input type="text" ref="test2"/>
        <input type="text" ref="test3"/>
  </div>
    )
 }
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/padsbanger/69z2wepo/9995/) I am working with.

I have a feeling that, this might not be a good idea to do, but I have no idea how to approach this atm.

Anyone help ?

Comment: Your code works just fine and I get the expected results in the console. The only this missing in the fiddle was to bind React library.

Comment: I am getting refs names not the values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `this.refs` is an object, you need to get the values, not the keys:

```
getAllRefsValues: function() {
    for (var ref in this.refs) {
        console.log(this.refs[ref]);
        console.log(this.refs[ref].getDOMNode()); 
    }
}
```

In my experience anyway, it is better to use [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) over `refs`.

Comment: Glad that helped, but really, try to avoid using refs as much as you can. In your use case and your use case only (accessing values of input elements) it is fine. React works __really well__ with callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I do this only because I have a lot of components and every has at least 10 input fields, so I want to create a mixin that will parse all the fields values and do an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#mapValues) you can iterate over `this.refs` and create simple object.

```
let data = _.mapValues(this.refs, function(ref) { return ref.value });
```